# How do time crystals not contradict thermodynamics?

Tags: condensed-matter, spacetime, symmetry-breaking, exotic-matter, time-crystals

Given that one of the basic properties of time crystals is that they move without any energy being applied, does that not mean that it's producing more energy than it's receiving? How does that not violate the first law of thermodynamics? Energy can't be created! So obviously I'm missing something: where is this movement coming from, and how does it not contradict everything we know and love about physics?

Comment: A planet moves in a periodic orbit and energy is not created. Plus in the experiment "to keep the ions out of equilibrium, the researchers alternately hit them with one laser to create an effective magnetic field and a second laser to partially flip the spins of the atoms"

Comment: @Albert But something had to put the energy into the planets for them to begin moving, and there's just nothing to stop them. Your second point is a valid one, though.

Comment: It does not matter how you made or if there is nothing to stop it. The point   is that an isolated system can be oscillating forever without consuming any energy.  Internal motion does not violate the first law.

Comment: @Albert I didn't mean that it continued moving. My point was that, unlike the time crystals, planets had *initial* energy to push them. But I had forgotten about the lasers, which means that the crystals do also.

Comment: Ok  , I got it!  .

Comment: In fact, at equilibrium time crystals are indeed forbidden: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.2143v3.pdf . The systems being described as time crystals are all non-equilibrium driven systems, so there's no problem here.